# new Obj, always or sometimes?

Tags: java, oop

**Should I always make new objects out of everything in java even if i know i will only use one?**

```
 obj = new obj();
 obj.method();
```

or just

```
classOfobject.method();
```

Why should I bother with the creation of a new obj in a situation like this?

Comment: It is situation based. If you are sure you won't use the object later you do not need to store it in an instance. However, what you are doing above is a different scenario. `classOfobject.method(); ` can only be invoked if `method()` is static. Also, a bit misleading title, as both cases utilizes 'OOP'.

Comment: Yes, but it wont matter if it's static if i´m only going to use that one default instance right?

Comment: If the method is static and you won't use anything else then no. There is no point in using `new` to create an instance of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`classOfObject.method()` only works if `method` is `static`.

Having said that, if your class truly represents a "thing", be that a user, a car, whatever, then you should make the method non-static and use `new` to make an object and invoke information on it.

If the class is a container for methods that don't have anything to do with objects themselves, e.g. a `Utils` class like `StringUtils`, then you can use static methods, e.g. `StringUtils.toUpperCase()`, and be happy with it.